# dc.js filtering on ordinal bar chart renders wrong bar width

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I realized an script with `dc.js` which has a range chart and an bar chart. If you filter the range chart the bar chart will be affected. Unfortunately the rendering of the bar width fails sometimes, when the filter only applies to one element. Here is a screenshot with the bug:

[image]

If I select more than one element it works:

[image]

Am I doing `sth.` wrong with the handling of ordinal scales?

Here's the relevant code:

```
//fake group, which sorts the elements and
//removes items with value smaller than one
var removeEmptyBinsAndSort = function(source_group) {
 return {
     all: function() {
         var orderFn = function(d) {
             return d;
         };

         blubb = source_group.order(orderFn)
             .top(Infinity).filter(function(d) {
                 return d.value > 1;
             });

         return blubb;
     },
 };
}

barChart
 .colors(d3.scale.category20())
 .dimension(dimensions.name)
 .group(groups.nameNoEmpty)
 .elasticY(true)
 .x(d3.scale.ordinal().range(groups.nameNoEmpty))
 .elasticX(true)
 .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal);
```

**Update**

I changed the issues mentioned by Gordon. But I still get same error. Here is the updated code:

```
var removeEmptyBinsAndSort = function(source_group) {

    var orderFn = function(d) {
        return d;
    };

    source_group.order(orderFn);

    var all = function() {
        return source_group.top(Infinity)
            .filter(function(d) {
                return d.value > 1.0;
            });
    };

    return {
        all: all,

        //returns all key values as sorted array
        domain: function() {
            return all().map(function(d) {
                return d.key;
            });
        }
    };
};

//The call in the bar chart is now
barChart
 .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(groups.nameNoEmpty.domain()))
```

Really strange is that it sometimes works and sometimes not. It's hard to reproduce.

Comment: That x scale parameter is wrong but probably harmless.  You usually don't want to set the range, since that is the screen coordinates (output) and dc.js sets that up already. The domain is the input, and it would take an array not a group. (d3 knows nothing about crossfilter.)

Comment: Also probably not relevant, but you only need to apply the order function once to your group.  (You could do this in the construction part of removeEmptyBinsAndSort, rather than the return part.)

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you very much for your answer. I've updated the code. Unfortunately no changes.

Comment: It certainly could be a dc.js bug, bar widths have been an issue in the past. Can you produce a fiddle? You say "sometimes"; is there a sequence of operations which causes it to show up?

Comment: I just played with the range slider in the range chart. I'll try to make fiddle later.

Comment: Thanks, I've [filed an issue here](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/790).  Being able to change the number of bars dynamically was only implemented recently [in response to this issue](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/593) and it seems pretty clear that not all cases work.